# PSSession on Computer with lower PSVersion. What Commands can I run?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have two servers, server A and server B.

Server A has PSVersion 5.0 and Server B has PSVersion 2.0.

If I create a PSSession on server A to server B like this:

```
$remotesession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverB    `
                               -Authentication Negotiate   `
                               -Port 5985                  `
                               -Credential $cred
```

And use `Invoke-Command -Session $remotesession -ScriptBlock { #stuff }` to use commands on server B, can I use PowerShell 5.0 commands since server A has a higher PowerShell Version? Or will Server B not recognize those?

the actual question would be, when I create a PSSession on a RemoteServer, which server says which PowerShell Version is in use?

Sorry for bad english, I couldn't describe my question very well so I hope you could understand what I'm trying to understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I use PowerShell 5.0 commands since server A has a higher PowerShell Version?

No. It will work in PSv2 environment.

> the actual question would be, when I create a PSSession on a RemoteServer, which server says which PowerShell Version is in use?

The one you create session on. ServerB in this particular case. You enter remote server's environment and can use it's commands.

**ADD:**

Have just checked to be sure. Connected from PSv2 client to PSv5 server and I am able to use specific PSv5 cmdlets i.e. `Compress-Archive`.